# Remove completely all packages I installed?

Tags: linux, package-management, command

I was using one Linux server with CentOS7 installed for testing and installing some tools. And now I don't remember how many packages I installed.

I want to remove all that packages so my server would be like new as it was. I don't want to search for every package and remove one by one.
Is there any way to remove them with just only one command?

Comment: `/var/log/yum.log` might be helpful, it lists both the package name and a timestamp. As far as I can see, it doesn't list packages added by the initial installs.

Comment: The yum.log file would list all packages I installed, but how could i delete all of them with only 1 command?

Comment: "Standard shell techniques" ;) like `sudo yum remove $(gawk '$0 ~ /Installed/ {printf "%s ", $NF}' /var/log/yum.log)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

List all the files in the reverse order of their installation date into a file:

```
rpm -qa --last >list
```

You'll get lines like

```
atop-2.1-1.fc22.x86_64                        Wed Apr 13 07:35:27 2016
telnet-server-0.17-60.fc22.x86_64             Mon Apr 11 20:10:43 2016
mhddfs-0.1.39-3.fc22.x86_64                   Sat Apr  9 21:26:06 2016
libpcap-devel-1.7.3-1.fc22.x86_64             Fri Apr  8 09:40:43 2016
```

Choose the cutoff date that applies to you and delete all the lines that follow it. Give the remaining lines to yum to remove, after removing the date part. Eg

```
sudo yum remove $(awk '{print $1}' <list)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also try with `yum history` and usually you get a numbered list of what has been installed, like :

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum history
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
ID | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
 3 | root <root>              | 2011-09-14 14:36 | Install        |    1   
 2 | root <root>              | 2011-09-12 15:48 | I, U           |   80   
 1 | System <unset>           | 2011-09-12 14:57 | Install        | 1025
```

and you can use afterwards `yum history undo 3` for example.

More details about yum history [here](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/yum-history-list-info-summary-repeat-redo-undo-new/).

Answer (score 0):

In order to rollback every history transactions, you could use the o-liner below:

```
# yum history list|awk '$1 ~ /[0-9]+/ {print $1}'| while read a; do yum history undo -y $a; done
```

Be cautious while running this command, because it will remove all your installed packages! If you want confirmation, you can remove the -y flag.